# Add Watermark to JPG or PNG proportionally using PHP

Tags: php, watermark

The problem I encountered right now is that the "watermark" image/file isn't proportionally correct. The height is a bit taller than expected.

As you can see from the preview below the "watermark" word/image was stretched.

```
<?php
//Source folder where all images are placed
$source="source";

//Destination folder where all images with watermark will be copied
$destination="output";

$watermark =imagecreatefrompng("watermark-sample.png");

//keeps the transparency of the picture
imagealphablending( $watermark, false );
imagesavealpha( $watermark, true );

//keeps the transparency of the picture
imagealphablending( $watermark, false );
imagesavealpha( $watermark, true );

// assign image file name
$image = $source.'/large-pic.jpg';

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

// get the height/width of the stamp image
$sx = imagesx($watermark);
$sy = imagesy($watermark);
$sximg = imagesx($im);

//percentage of the size(5%)
$percent = $sximg * 0.12;

//position the stamp to the center
$posx = round(imagesx($im) / 2) - round($sx / 2);
$posy = round(imagesy($im) / 2) - round($sy / 2);

//Create the final resized watermark stamp
$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($percent, $percent);

//keeps the transparency of the picture
imagealphablending( $dest_image, false );
imagesavealpha( $dest_image, true );

//resizes the stamp
imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $percent, $percent, $sx, $sy);

// Copy the resized stamp image onto the photo
imagecopy($im, $dest_image, round($posx), round($posy), 0, 0, $percent, $percent);

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Output Image:
[image]

Watermark Image:
[image]

Comment: By using `$percent, $percent` for the new image's width and height in `imagecopyresampled`, you are _forcing_ the image to be square. Since your _original_ watermark image did _not_ have a 1:1 aspect ratio, of course this gets you a "stretched" image.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out @CBroe, will try to explore and debug this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to maintain the aspect ratio of a resized watermark at 5% of the background image size you need to know the ratio of width to height and use that when generating the resized image. As per the comment by @CBroe, using a single `$percent` value for both will yield the wrong aspect ratio! The positioning of the watermark also requires the new watermark sizes to be able to calculate the appropriate image centre.

The two initial uses of:

```
imagealphablending( $watermark, false );
imagesavealpha( $watermark, true );
```

were not required and can be removed.

The `header` call at the end should be set to `image/png` as you then use `imagepng` to output the composite image to the browser.

---

```
<?php

# Source folder where all images are placed
$source=__DIR__ . '/source';

# As the $destination folder/variable was unused it is gone.


$watermark = imagecreatefrompng( $source . '/watermark-sample.png' );
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg( $source . '/large-pic.jpg' );



# get the height/width of the watermark image
$sx = imagesx( $watermark );
$sy = imagesy( $watermark );
$sximg = imagesx( $im );


# very important - aspect ratio of the watermark!!!
$ratio=$sx / $sy;

# percentage of the size( 5% )
$percent = 5 / 100; # 5% as per question



# Determine new sizes for the watermark.
# The width will be 5% of the background width
# but the height will be the respective proportion
# of the background height based upon the aspect
# ratio of the watermark!

$width = $sximg * $percent;
$height = $width / $ratio;



# Determine the position the watermark on the background image and
# use the new sizes of watermark as part of the centre calculations!
$posx = round( imagesx( $im ) / 2 ) - round( $width / 2 );
$posy = round( imagesy( $im ) / 2 ) - round( $height / 2 );





# Create the final resized watermark stamp
$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );

# keeps the transparency of the picture
imagealphablending( $dest_image, false );
imagesavealpha( $dest_image, true );


# resizes the stamp
imagecopyresampled( $dest_image, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $sx, $sy );

# Copy the resized stamp image onto the photo
imagecopy( $im, $dest_image, round( $posx ), round( $posy ), 0, 0, $width, $height );



# Output and free memory - use correct header however!
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng( $im );

imagedestroy( $im );
imagedestroy( $watermark );
?>
```

---

What I ended up with whilst playing about:

```
<?php

    error_reporting( 0 );

    $config=json_decode(
        json_encode(
            ( array(
                    'percentage'    =>  10,
                    'save'          =>  true,                                   # save composite image to disk.
                    'both'          =>  true,                                   # both save & output in same operation.
                    'quality'       =>  0,                                      # Compression level: from 0 (no compression) to 9. default: 6
                    'filters'       =>  PNG_NO_FILTER,                          # Bitmask of filter constants to achieve particular effects.
                    'download'      =>  true,                                   # Download source images from internet if needed
                    'force'         =>  false,                                  # Force overwrite of source images if new background is used etc
                    'urls'          =>  array(
                        'watermark'         =>  'https://i.imgur.com/YoiJKXC.png',
                        'background'        =>  'https://res.cloudinary.com/dk-find-out/image/upload/q_80,w_1920,f_auto/MA_00089970_icgvox.jpg'
                    ),
                    'folders'       =>  array(
                        'source'            =>  __DIR__ . '/images/uploads',    # Directory used for the two source images
                        'destination'       =>  __DIR__ . '/images/composites'  # Directory to save composite image into if being saved.
                    ),
                    'align'         =>  array(
                        'horizontal'    =>  'center',                           # center, left, right
                        'vertical'      =>  'middle'                            # middle, top, bottom
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );





    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Create the directory structure defined in the config if it does not exist.
    # If this happens logically the images cannot exist so the script will terminate below.
    # Override this by allowing download of source images.
    foreach( $config->folders as $folder ){
        if( !file_exists( $folder ) ){
            mkdir( $folder, 0777, true );
            clearstatcache();
        }
    }

    # download source images from interweb if needed and save to the source directory defined above.
    if( $config->download && count( array_keys( get_object_vars( $config->urls ) ) ) > 0 ){
        foreach( $config->urls as $folder => $url ){
            $src=sprintf( '%s/%s', $config->folders->source, basename( $url ) );
            if( !file_exists( $src ) or $config->force ){
                file_put_contents( $src, file_get_contents( $url ) );
            }
            clearstatcache();
        }
    }
    
    
    switch( pathinfo( basename( $config->urls->background ), PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ){
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg': 
        case 'pjpeg': $func='imagecreatefromjpeg'; break;
        case 'png':   $func='imagecreatefrompng';  break;
        case 'gif':   $func='imagecreatefromgif';  break;
        case 'webp':  $func='imagecreatefromwebp'; break;
        case 'bmp':   $func='imagecreatefrombmp';  break;
    }


    # create the two base images upon which the composite will be based.
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng( sprintf( '%s/%s', $config->folders->source, basename( $config->urls->watermark ) ) );
    $srcimage  = call_user_func( $func, sprintf( '%s/%s', $config->folders->source, basename( $config->urls->background ) ) );

    # if the images do not exist, terminate the script.
    if( !$watermark or !$srcimage ) exit('Bad Foo! One or other source images could not be created.');


    # get the width / height of the watermark image & the ratio of with to height.
    $wm_img_x = imagesx( $watermark );
    $wm_img_y = imagesy( $watermark );
    $ratio = $wm_img_x / $wm_img_y;


    # get width / height of background image
    $src_img_x = imagesx( $srcimage );
    $src_img_y = imagesy( $srcimage );





    #   The watermark is to be X% of the size of the background image
    #   but to retain the proportionality of the watermark - for this
    #   we need to know the ratio of width to height in order to
    #   determine new width & height of watermark image.
    $wm_width = $src_img_x * ( $config->percentage / 100 );
    $wm_height = round( $wm_width / $ratio, 2 );



    # identify centre of background image - this is where the watermark will be placed.
    $posx = round( $src_img_x / 2 ) - round( $wm_width / 2 );
    $posy = round( $src_img_y / 2 ) - round( $wm_height / 2 );

    # set the location of watermark if not at default center/middle point.
    if( strtolower( $config->align->horizontal ) == 'left' )$posx=10;
    if( strtolower( $config->align->horizontal ) == 'right' )$posx=$src_img_x - ( $wm_width + 10 );

    if( strtolower( $config->align->vertical ) == 'top' )$posy=10;
    if( strtolower( $config->align->vertical ) == 'bottom' )$posy=$src_img_y - ( $wm_height + 10 );




    # create the composite output image that will be populated next.
    $output = imagecreatetruecolor( $src_img_x, $src_img_y );
    imagealphablending( $output, true );
    imagesavealpha( $output, true );



    # copy the background to the output image
    imagecopy( $output, $srcimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_img_x, $src_img_y );
    # add the new resized watermark with it's transparency to the output
    imagecopyresampled( $output, $watermark, $posx, $posy, 0, 0, $wm_width, $wm_height, $wm_img_x, $wm_img_y );



    # direct output or save to disk?
    $filepath=$config->save ? sprintf('%s/composite.png', $config->folders->destination ) : null;



    // Save/Output and free memory.
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng( $output, $filepath, $config->quality, $config->filters );
    if( $config->both ) imagepng( $output );


    imagedestroy( $watermark );
    imagedestroy( $srcimage );
    imagedestroy( $output );
?>
```

Comment: I tried this code but I got an empty result, just a very small white box. Anyway, thank you so much for this solution with clean comments

I found the error ` PHP Deprecated:  Implicit conversion from float 15.942028985507246 to int loses precision in`

Will try to debug this right now. Thank you @professor

Comment: Finally, I was able to solve this by swapping all the **$width** & **$height** in **intval()**

Comment: I'm sorry that this didn't immediately resolve your issue ( in testing it was fine on win7 ) but I'm glad that you have arrived at a solution... good luck with further coding adventures!

Comment: No worries @prof and wow, I'm about to post an additional question regarding the positioning of the "watermark" aside from "center - center". But you coded already a solution, please let me try this code, and will get you if I encountered something.

Comment: Tried it already and I got this error **Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "imagecreatefromjpeg"**

I'm using PHP 8.

Comment: you might want to put those `imagecreatefromXXX` within quotes - it works fine in PHP 7.2

Comment: I was able to use the 1st set of code and play around to get the quick solution to set the "top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right" position using this code. 

`
`// Top right corner of the image`
`//$posx = ($sximg - $width) - 10;`
`//$posy = 10;`

`// Top left corner of the watermark`
`//$posx = 10;`
`//$posy = 10;`

`// Bottom left corner of the watermark`
`//$posx = 10;`
`//$posy = imagesy( $im ) - $height - 10;`

`// Bottom right corner of the watermark`
`$posx = imagesx( $im ) - $width - 10;`
`$posy = imagesy( $im ) - $height - 10;`
`

Comment: Hi @Prof, I'm happy to update you that the last revision of your code was working already :)

Comment: Hi @professor, I got this "int / float" error when using Strict_type 
`Uncaught TypeError: imagecopyresampled(): Argument #3 ($dst_x) must be of type int, float given`

I tried adding (int) but it doesn't work.
PHP8 with Strict_type(1) enabled.

Comment: I got it woking!
Here's the code.

`imagecopyresampled( $output, $watermark, (int)round($posx), (int)round($posy), 0, 0, (int)$wm_width, (int)$wm_height,
    $wm_img_x, $wm_img_y );`